# Find the biggest number from given data below

Tags: big-numbers

**Maths problem :**

$$(9^{62773} + 2)^{83721}$$ Now here is the rest of the problem. After finding the huge number I have to find its digital sum. If you don't know what that means just give me the answer to the problem. 
Please try to solve it also please tell me the method just try avoiding using $\log$.

I tried using $\log$ but as it was not allowed. I couldn't find a calculator which could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can ignore the powers of $9$ because they do not impact the digital sum.  Now we are looking for $2^{83721} \pmod 9$.  If you just compute the powers of $2 \pmod 9$ you will find they cycle.  What is the cycle length?  Now you just need the remainder of $83721$ divided by the cycle length.

Comment: can u explain me in little detailed form

Comment: The digital root of a number is the same as the remainder left when dividing it by $9$ (except for substituting $9$ for $0$).  We are trying to evaluate that.